# Node Using JSON-Stat

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to use JSONStat toolkit for the first time. However I keep getting this error

```
        let method = init.method || input.method || 'GET';
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of null
    at new Request (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1217:21)
    at /app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1439:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (/app/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1437:9)
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/jsonstat-toolkit/main.cjs:2:15410)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
```

code when running:

```
const JSONstat = require("jsonstat-toolkit");
JSONstat( "https://json-stat.org/samples/oecd-canada-col.json" , function() {
    if( this.class==="collection" ){
        var ds1=this.Dataset( 0 );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Can you say which version of JSONstat you are using?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonstat-toolkit I just did npm i jsonstat-toolkit(https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonstat-toolkit) today. So I am guessing 1.4.1

Comment: Look in your package.json file, it will show the version, but yes should be 1.4.1

Comment: Please provide the stack trace with the error (the part that shows the line numbers)

Comment: I ran it manually to get the stack trace. I'll edit the question

Comment: Do you think installing an earlier version will help?

Comment: Yes, you will need to downgrade. There is a problem with the package. You should open an issue on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/jsonstat/toolkit/issues) or email the author.

Comment: Put the answer in the answer space below. Don't edit the question to include the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issued fixed in verison 1.4.2;
https://github.com/jsonstat/toolkit/issues/2#issuecomment-1079877683

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the syntax for the v0.x of JSONstat. The [example](https://github.com/jsonstat/toolkit/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md#version-1-1) clearly shows the correct use.

Change `this` to be a parameter that you accept as an argument to the function:

```
const JSONstat = require("jsonstat-toolkit");
JSONstat( "https://json-stat.org/samples/oecd-canada-col.json" , function(j) {
    if( j.class==="collection" ){
        var ds1=j.Dataset( 0 );
    }
} );
```

<del>Even with the correct code, version 1.4.1 seems to fail. Downgrading the package to 1.3.2 seems to fix it: `npm i jsonstat-toolkit@1.3`.</del>  **UPDATE** This has been [fixed in 1.4.2](https://github.com/jsonstat/toolkit/issues/2#issuecomment-1079888408) thanks to OP's bug report.

Alternatively, downgrade to version 0 and keep your same syntax (using `this`): `npm un jsonstat-toolkit && npm i jsonstat`.

Comment: What I have in the question is my entire code, am I wrong in saying that require("jsonstat-toolkit") might be the problem?

Comment: @OleDybedokken oh, sorry -- so the error is not occurring in your actual code? We'll need the stack trace, then. Likely it will be a problem with JSONstat though, and you should probably open a bug with that library

Comment: @OleDybedokken My pleasure! Sorry for the wrong initial answer

Comment: I reported the issue and it has now been fixed in version 1.4.2. Maybe update your answer to inform others?